# How to create python package with different classes without importing each one

Tags: python, package, pypi

I created a package in Pypi and did the following setting.
Lets say that my package is called "myproj".
So I put all the different files in myproj/
And to use them I have to do

`from myproj.myclass1 import myclass1`

And I would like it to work like

```
from myproj import myproj
```

and then I could use all functions from different classes like

```
myproj.class1func()
myproj.class2func()
```

My setup

```
setup(
name="myproj",
version=VERSION,
description="PyProj package",
long_description=readme(),
long_description_content_type='text/x-rst',
url="",
author="",
author_email="",
license="MIT",
classifiers=[
],
keywords='myproj',
packages=["myproj"],
py_modules=[],
install_requires=["numpy", "matplotlib", "cvxopt", "pyswarm", "scipy", "typing", "pandas"],
include_package_data=True,
python_requires='>=3',
cmdclass={
    'verify': VerifyVersionCommand,
})
```

Comment: I've never put anything on PyPi but I'm pretty sure that what you want to do has nothing to do with PyPi and has everything to do with how you structure the modules in your *package*; the classes in your modules and what you put in the  `__init__.py`'s.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your classes (eg, `myclass1` and `myclass2`) into the file `myproj/__init__.py`.

```
# myproj/__init__.py
class myclass1:
    def __init__(self):
        self._thing1 = 1
    def doit(self):
        print('Hello from myclass1.')

class myclass2:
    def __init__(self):
        self._thing2 = 2
    def doit(self):
        print('Hello from myclass2.')
```

Then you can do this:

```
import myproj

c1 = myproj.myclass1()
c1.doit()
c2 = myproj.myclass2()
c2.doit()
```